# Add New Varchar2 Field in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle

I'm new to Oracle.  I need to add a varchar2 field to an existing table which is 50 bytes in length.

I right clicked on the table like this:
[image]

...Then I arrive at this field:
[image]

I do not know what to do here. I was expecting to see a 'type', 'size'and 'units' prompt like in the schema-design-GUI view (where I would enter ~varchar2, 45, and bytes respectively). I don't know what to make of the precisions and scale fields; I thought those were for numbers.

Comment: Why not just try it and see what happens?

Comment: @APC I don't want to break my build. I'd like to be sure. I would have never guessed that precision had to do with varchars. I said I'm new to Oracle. I took the time to ask in away that may be helpful to others. I don't understand the negativity.

Comment: A string has a specific length, hence we need precision.  Scale does only apply to numbers but I guess SQL Developer doesn't have a very flexible property UI.

Comment: As for "negativity" I don't see why it's negative to suggest you experiment with the tool.  You won't "break your build".  If you do something which is syntactically illegal the statement will fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're adding a column. Give it a name ("Column Name"), a type (select from "Data Type" drop-down), and a length ("Precision").  If it's a NUMBER type, you can give it a scale (place to the right of the decimal).  In your specific example, give your column a name, leave data type drop-down at VARCHAR2, and specify 50 for precision.

Comment: I had same problem - no idea that _Precision_ means _Length_ (why don't they just put _Length_?). Still don't see how _Scale_ can have anything to do with a _VARCHAR2_...